# Trying to extract xyz from multipolygon shapefile

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, extract, xyz

I want to extract the x, y and z from shapefile polygon vertices where the geometry is multipolygon.  Once extracted would like to have them in a geopandas data frame. I have seen a couple of approaches however the problem seems to be that when the shapefile is imported I can't get it to a feature that has a Z attribute.  For example, the following works to get the x and y only, using a shapefile that was generated from ArcGIS Pro by converting the multipolygon format to its single parts.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("C:/FG3D_2019/code/Collada_Geospatial/Boston_Mesh_Evaluation/Boston_Bldg1_SingleParts.shp")
print('gdf type', type(gdf))
geom_uu = gdf.unary_union
# Extract the point values that define the perimeter of the polygon
x, y = geom_uu.exterior.coords.xy
```

What I would like is to get the z coordinates from the geometry field so essentially;
`x, y, z = geom_uu.exterior.coords.xyz`.

Has anyone had luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polygon = Polygon([[0.0, 0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 1.0, 4.O], [0.0, 1.0, 5.0]])
x,y,z = zip(*polygon.exterior.coords)
print(x)
(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
print(y)
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
print(z)
(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: Thank you gene, that worked.